# How to make Semantic-UI sidebar work?

Tags: semantic-ui

I'm just stuck, heres my codepen, what am I doing wrong?

http://codepen.io/lastnoob/pen/zvKNmo

```
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="ui left inverted vertical menu sidebar">
      <div class="item">
        <button id="hide-sidebar" class="button">
          <i class="sidebar icon"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
      <a class="item">
        Item 1
      </a>
      <a class="item">
        Item 2
      </a>
      <a class="item">
        Item 3
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="pusher">
      <div id="show-sidebar" class="button toggler">
        <i class="sidebar icon"></i>
        Sidebar
      </div>      
      <!-- Site content !-->
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
  $(function() {
    $('#show-sidebar').click(function() {
      $('#show-sidebar').hide();
      $('.menu.sidebar').sidebar('toggle');
    });

    $('#hide-sidebar').click(function() {
      $('#show-sidebar').show();
      $('.menu.sidebar').sidebar('toggle');
    });
  });
```

It doesnt really do anything, my sidebar is not showing up, not doing anything.

Comment: The code is fine, you just need jQuery before the semantic library in your settings.

Comment: Oh my god, thanks!! I was going crazy I was trying for like 2 hours now. Thanks!